# TestNG assertion message not display the text after the word expected

Tags: java, testng

Hey all I have a question regards TestNG
I have this assertion in the test

```
Assert.assertTrue(exPublisherPaymentObject.getPaymentZipCode().equals(insertBillingInformtionPage().getPaymentyZipCode()),"Error in validating payment zip code expected " + exPublisherPaymentObject.getPaymentZipCode() + " actual " + insertBillingInformtionPage().getPaymentyZipCode());
```

When it fails the error message is  `Error in validating payment city`
and not the full message, However if I change the word expected to expects it display the full message.
it it a bug? in testNG since the word expected is inside "" meanning a string